# CGAL: Severe performance problems and memory corruption performing boolops on bezier polygons

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, valgrind, cgal, memory-corruption

After wrestling with this for days, I'm about to submit this as a bug report but thought I'd post it here in case someone knows of a fix or workaround.

I cannot tell if this is one bug or many, but there is a simple way to reproduce it by modifying the bezier_traits_adapter2 example in Boolean_set_operations_2. It manifests differently depending on the build type (Release or Debug).

Running the demo on the default files char_g.bps and char_m.bps works fine and takes only a few milliseconds. However, on certain shapes (see shape1.bps and shape2.bps below) it succeeds only on the first attempt, and fails if you rebuild all the polygons a second time. In debug mode it results in an assertion failure (but not always the same assertion); in release mode it results in a segmentation fault.

[shape1.bps](https://gist.github.com/RobJinman/2eaeb61b01f8e408dd92)
[shape2.bps](https://gist.github.com/RobJinman/109e1d60c54c5193b26d)

In examples/Boolean_set_operations_2/bezier_traits_adapter2.cpp, add a for loop to the main function:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  const char* filename1 = (argc > 1) ? argv[1] : "char_g.bps";
  const char* filename2 = (argc > 2) ? argv[2] : "char_m.bps";
  const char* bop       = (argc > 3) ? argv[3] : "i";

  for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {

    // Read the general polygons from the input files.
    CGAL::Timer timer;
    Bezier_polygon_set S1, S2;

    timer.start();


    if (! read_bezier(filename1, S1)) {
      std::cerr << "Failed to read " << filename1 << " ..." << std::endl;
      return 1;
    }

    if (! read_bezier(filename2, S2)) {
      std::cerr << "Failed to read " << filename2 << " ..." << std::endl;
      return 1;
    }

    timer.stop();
    std::cout << "Constructed the input polygons in " << timer.time()
              << " seconds." << std::endl << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Starting boolean operation..." << std::endl;
    timer.reset();
    timer.start();
    try {
      switch (bop[0]) {
        case 'i': S1.intersection(S2); break;
        case 'u': S1.join(S2); break;
      }
    }
    catch(std::exception const& x) {
      std::cout << "An exception occurred during the Boolean operation:"
                << x.what() << std::endl;
    }
    catch(...) {
      std::cout << "An exception occurred during the Boolean operation."
                << std::endl;
    }
    timer.stop();

    std::cout << "The " << ( bop[0] == 'i' ? "intersection" : "union" )
              << " computation took "
              << timer.time() << " seconds." << std::endl;

  }

  return 0;
}
```

Now if you run the program on the default data, it will succeed, but it's VERY slow - it takes around 40 seconds. On my custom data, in debug mode, the first iteration always succeeds and all subsequent iterations fail with assertion failures. In release mode, the first three iterations always succeed, but the fourth will usually segfault. Running the program under valgrind shows errors, but only when the loop is set to 4 iterations or more; if you change the constant to 3 there are no errors and everything works fine. Sometimes, the RAM usage will shoot up to over 3 GB and I have to rush to kill the process before my machine becomes unresponsive.

[Valgrind output](https://gist.github.com/RobJinman/08ff90da385c529c503b)

I'm trying to use CGAL to merge font glyphs with a watermark, and I'm calling into my C++ library from Python. I noticed that I was getting segfaults on certain glyphs and after some investigation realised that a dodgy glyph will always succeed if processed first. There doesn't appear to be anything visibly wrong with the shapes it fails on, but when it does succeed the resulting polygon union, once converted from X-monotone subcurves into full bezier curves using CGAL::de_casteljau_2, is horrendously inaccurate. [Here](http://postimg.org/image/u01rezn1z/) is an example. Notice the large gaps.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you have a segmentation fault you should you be able to produce a backtrace from the core dump. Alternatively launch it in gdb to get a live backtrace.

Comment: @g24l Well, obviously. I've given the Valgrind output, which shows where the invalid reads occur. It doesn't really help me diagnose the problem as it looks like a bug. I'm hoping someone more familiar with the inner workings of the library might know what's going on.

Comment: em, do you know what a "core dump" is?

Comment: Also every time you run a for loop, the polygon set is appended with itself, that's usually not good.